# How to make a value into clickable value in laravel nova?

Tags: html, laravel, anchor, laravel-nova

I am using laravel-nova for my UI pages,i have one value which should be displayed as masked value based on the some logic up to this part it's working fine .Now my requirement is the masked value should support the **clickable** based on that i have to reveal the original value can you please help me to acheive this thing in laravel nova ..?

```
 Text::make('coupon', 'coupon_number')
                ->displayUsing(function(){
                    $hashed_value=Str::mask($this->coupon_number, '#', '0','3');
                    $original_value = $this->coupon_number;
                    return "<a href='#' style = 'text-decoration:none;color:black'>$hashed_value</a>";
                })->asHtml()
                ->creationRules('nullable', 'digits:9')
                ->hideFromIndex()
                ->nullable()
```

**expected functionality**:- on click of the hashed value it should show the original value again on click of original value it should be mask